# Need assistance fixing r code for cross-validation

Tags: r, cross-validation

I need help fixing this code. I'm trying to conduct cross-validation. The error generated is:

> 'newdata' had 19 rows but variables found have 77 rows

Based on previous questions, the issue seems too be how I am referencing my `train.exprs` and `train.d2r` for the `pval` line of code. In the case of `train.d2r(is vector of num[1:77]) while train.exprs( is matrix num [1:12625, 1:77])`.

```
set.seed(1234)
# calculate days-to-remission:
ALL.pdat <- pData(ALL)
date.cr.chr <- as.character(ALL.pdat$date.cr)
diag.chr <- as.character(ALL.pdat$diagnosis)
date.cr.t <- strptime(date.cr.chr,"%m/%d/%Y")
diag.t <- strptime(diag.chr,"%m/%d/%Y")
ALL.pdat$D2R <- as.numeric(date.cr.t - diag.t)
# prepare the data structures:
ALL.exprs <- exprs(ALL)[,!is.na(ALL.pdat$D2R)]
ALL.pdat <- ALL.pdat[!is.na(ALL.pdat$D2R),]
n.xval <- 5
s2.xval <- numeric()
xval.grps <- sample(1:dim(ALL.pdat)[1]%%n.xval+1)
# run over each cross-validation:
for ( i.xval in 1:n.xval ) {
min.pval <- 1.0
min.id <- NA
train.exprs <- ALL.exprs[,xval.grps!=i.xval]
train.d2r <- ALL.pdat[xval.grps!=i.xval,"D2R"]
# evaluate each gene in the training dataset to find the one
# most associated with the outcome:
for( i in 1:dim(train.exprs)[1]) {
###for( i in 1:100 ) {
p.val <- anova(lm(train.d2r~train.exprs[i,],))[1,"Pr(>F)"]
if ( p.val < min.pval ) {
min.pval <- p.val
min.id <- i
}
}
# print the gene found:
cat(rownames(train.exprs)[min.id],min.pval,fill=T)
# refit the model for best gene found on training dataset:
best.lm.xval <- lm(train.d2r~train.exprs[min.id,])
# calculate predictions on test dataset:
test.exprs <- ALL.exprs[,xval.grps==i.xval]
test.d2r <- ALL.pdat[xval.grps==i.xval,"D2R"]
test.pred <- predict(
best.lm.xval,data.frame(t(test.exprs),test.d2r)
)
# accumulate squared errors of prediction:
s2.xval <- c(s2.xval,(test.pred-test.d2r)^2)
}
```

Comment: From Review: Most probably this is not the cause of the issue, but I believe there is a missing `}` at the end of your source code, at least here in your question.

Comment: Sorry if this is an unhelpful suggestion. But there are many prediction packages with built-in cross validation, and frameworks such as `caret` that handle all sorts of train/test cases. Unless you are doing this for coursework - respectfully -- it's best not to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @sɐunıɔןɐqɐp sorry about that, just edited the code fragment to reflect the complete code.

Comment: @Stephen Henderson , thanks for the recommendation. This is part of my coding exercise as new R learner.